# get_queryset is executed and not get_object

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to use `get_object` to retrieve a single object from my database. However, my code always enters into `get_queryset` and not `get_object` so I always return a list of objects.

Here is my viewset :

```
class DiagramView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Diagram.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DiagramSerializer
    pk_url_kwarg = 'id'

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.queryset.get(id=kwargs.get('id'))

    def get_queryset(self):
        print('im here')
```

My route is :

```
router.register('api/diagramsingle', DiagramView, 'diagramsingle')
```

And I access this route like this :

```
api/diagramsingle/?id=1
```

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If it is a simple router, it will work with `api/diagramsingle/1/`, so not in the *querystring*, but in the *path*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is written in the [documentation on routers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage), for a `SimpleRouter`, the detail view has as pattern `api/diagramsingle/<int:pk>/`, so you access a single object with:

```
api/diagramsingle/1/
```

where you specify the primary key in the *path*, not in the *querystring*.